# Rails: Thread.Current hash for request scoped data sharing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am planning to use Thread.Current hash in ruby to have information shared per request scope in my Rails application. (I know this is may not be the best design decision and might even be breaking MVC).
I am looking at the approach mentioned here http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/lets-stop-polluting-the-threadcurrent-hash/

This basically adds a thread_local_accessor method to the Class and provides sweeping when the given thread goes out of scope. Does anyone know if this has any other limitations or any gotchas that I should be aware of? Or any other alternative to request level hashes that is cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you link to is not thread safe. It uses ruby's Hash class which is not thread safe. You could guard access using one of ruby's synchronization primitives, e.g. Mutex.

Also, I'm not convinced that using a global data structure indexed by thread id is any better than just using Thread.current.

If you're worried about key collision, why not choose a unique key, like a GUID. Building on the example in the link that you provided:

```
class ThreadedLibrary
  @@LIBRARY_ID = 'D0052660-60E6-4624-B08E-ECA9200B2949'
  Thread.current[@@LIBRARY_ID] = {}

  def self.some_setting= val
    Thread.current[@@LIBRARY_ID][:some_setting] = val
  end

  def self.some_setting
    Thread.current[@@LIBRARY_ID][:some_setting] ||= :default
  end
end
```